# Asynchrounous Chunked File Upload in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload

I'm trying to asynchronously upload file chunks from a .Net client to a php web server using HttpClient in C#.

I can chunk the file just fine, and upload those chunks to the remote server, but I'm not sure if this is really running asynchronously. Ideally, I would upload the chunks in parallel to maximize upload speed. My code is as follows:

```
//Call to chunk and upload file in another async method. I'm only showing the call here:
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileNameIn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            await ChunkFileAsync(fileStream, uploadFile.Name, url);

// To chunk the file
        public static async Task<bool> ChunkFileAsync(FileStream fileStream, string fileName, string url)
        {
            int chunkSize = 102400; // Upload 1mb at a time
            int totalChunks = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)fileStream.Length / chunkSize);
            // Loop through the whole stream and send it chunk by chunk asynchronously;
            bool retVal = true;
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
           try {
                for (int i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++)
                {
                    int startIndex = i * chunkSize;
                    int endIndex = (int)(startIndex + chunkSize > fileStream.Length ? fileStream.Length : startIndex + chunkSize);
                    int length = endIndex - startIndex;

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
                    fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                    Task task = SendChunkRequest(fileName, url, i, bytes);
                    tasks.Add(task);                    
                    retVal = true;
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR - There was an error chunking the file before sending the request " + e.Message);
                retVal = false;
            }
            return retVal;

        }

//To upload chunks to remote server
        public static async Task<bool> SendChunkRequest(string fileName, string url, int loopCounter, Byte[] bytes)
        {
            bool response = false;
            try
            {

                ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
                ByteArrayContent data = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
                data.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
                byte[] strParamsBytes = ascii.GetBytes(strVals);
                HttpClient requestToServer = new HttpClient();
                MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                form.Add(data, "file", fileName + loopCounter);
                await requestToServer.PostAsync(url, form);
                requestToServer.Dispose();
                response = true;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There was an exception: " + e);
            }
            return response;
        }
```

If I upload a 100Mb file, I see all ten chunks uploaded to the server one at a time. Can I make this code more efficient? Any help is greatly appreciated.